# Containerizing Snakemake pipeline in Docker, while also using Docker for independent env control

Tags: docker, containers, bioinformatics, cicd, snakemake

Im having some troubles architecting my Snakemake workflow with Docker.

Briefly, I am trying to dockerize the "Snakemake bits" (eg: snakefile, script, etc) and independently dockerize each env. I want this for portability and testing – a singular, massive Docker image is hard to manage with CI/CD tools. I will be frequently building and deploying my pipeline(s) – Docker images >10 gb are difficult or impossible to work with on many CI/CD platforms. My env docker images will be relatively stable rarely needing to be rebuilt (eg: just containing samtools).

For example, lets say I have a dockerfile that looks something like this:

```
FROM conda
RUN conda install snakemake 
COPY my_repo
```

Then within the snakefile, you have rules that looks like this:

```
rule example:
    input: "data" 
    output: "different_data" 
    container: "docker://repo/env"
    script: "script.py"
```

I believe the initial container would itself need to have Docker, which seems not correct and overly complex. Keeping the Snakemake bits *not* in a container is also not ideal – these pipelines need to be very portable. ie, one container will be the "master" container orchestrating the others.

Currently I am planning on investigating Docker outside of Docker (DooD, mounting the local docker socket), but is there perhaps a cleaner way to achieve what I want?

Edit: as far as I know (please correct me if I am wrong) Snakemake only uses Apptainer/Singularity, not Docker. Everything else in this post still remains the same though.

Comment: What about the built-in containerization options in snakemake, esp. `--containerize`?

Comment: That creates one giant container created from the conda envs, no?

Comment: Yes, sorry Imissed your original point about massive containers.

Answer (score 1):

Your architecture:

```
[ Host Machine ]
      |
      |----[ Master Container (Snakemake + Docker CLI) ]
                |
                |----[ Worker Container 1 (Environment 1) ]
                |
                |----[ Worker Container 2 (Environment 2) ]
                |
                |----[ ]
```

Your master container will be based on a lightweight image, but must include both [Snakemake](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html) and the Docker CLI. The Docker CLI is necessary to manage other containers from within the master container.

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

# Install Docker CLI and other dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl python3 python3-pip && \
    curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh && \
    sh get-docker.sh && \
    apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli

# Install Snakemake using pip
RUN pip3 install snakemake

# Copy your Snakemake workflow files into the container
COPY . /workflow
WORKDIR /workflow
```

Use [Docker outside of Docker (DooD)](https://rusingh.com/docker-outside-of-docker/) by mounting the host's Docker socket into the master container. That allows the master container to communicate with the host's Docker daemon to manage worker containers.

```bash
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it my_master_container
```

You do specify worker containers in the Snakemake rules: Snakemake allows specifying containers for each rule, enabling different environments for different steps of the workflow.

As you noted, Snakemake natively supports container technologies like [Singularity (Apptainer)](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#apptainer/singularity) rather than Docker, due to security and portability considerations in HPC environments. However, for Docker compatibility, especially in CI/CD pipelines and cloud environments, the strategy above (using Docker CLI within the master container) can work around this limitation.